# How can I make a database connection from the branch template in the javascripts section in symfony 5.4?

Tags: javascript, mysql, symfony

I want to make a connection to the database with nodule and js in twig but when I put the code it gives me an error saying that require is not defined when if I do it in a js file it shows me everything perfectly this is my code

```
let mysql = require('mysql')

                    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
                        host: 'localhost',
                        user: 'root',
                        password: '',
                        database: 'tfc'
                    });

                    connection.connect((err) => {
                        if(err){
                            throw err
                        }else{
                            console.log('La conexión ha sido un éxito')
                        }
                    })

                    connection.query('select * from calendar',(err,data) => {
                        if(err){
                            throw err
                        }else{
                            console.log(data)
                        }
                    })

                    connection.end()
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `require('mysql')` in PHP code?

Comment: @Justinas Not only have I used it in the branch scripts tag, I try?